# Which DB should I use?

Tags: python, database

I am looking for a DB to store list of float numbers. And has a good support in pyhton. I have found some options but not sure which one is the best.. Probably all  DBs are good for this.
I will need one primary key, so probably some SQL db.
Which one has to best support in python and is easy to use? Which one is the best to store lists of numbers in? I do not expect high volume of data. Max few thousands or records.
Thanks for your recommendation and your opinion. :)

Comment: How large is the data set?

Comment: each list will have 125 values that looks like "0.456145678" i will have few hundreds max few thousands of these lists. the performance should not be problem.

Comment: Perhaps just use a simple CSV file, one row per record?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an expert at this, but for small data sets that will fit in RAM, I think the standard recommendation is the [SQLite library](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html). I used this once on a small project and it worked very well. Depending on what you want to do with the data, you might well be served using [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) dataframes, however you don't provide enough information to assess that.

Comment: The final solution is to go for MySQL :) It has very good python support and works well. Also I would personally never go on production with SQLite. Thanks

Comment: @jv95 If you are considering MySQL, you should probably also consider MariaDB and PostgreSQL.